# Sublime Text 3 SFTP using private key

Tags: ssh, sublime-text-3

I'm trying to set up an SSH connection on a windows 7 computer. I have generated the keys using PuTTYGen and loaded the private key into Pageant too. When I try to browse the server directory Sublime asks me for a password to the user rather than the passphrase of the key file as if I didn't have a private key.

So far I have tried these things suggested on the internet:

- setting the connection type to sftp and ftp, no luck
- use IP and domain name for the host variable, no luck
- use the key file name as the username, no luck
- enable/disable connect_timeout, no luck
- moving around the private key into different locations including desktop, `All Users` folder, `my user folder`, root of `C:/`, root of `D:/`, `My Documents` folder, `Sublime 3` folder, no luck
- I tried to type in the passphrase to my PK when prompt to enter the password to root@some.host.com and got an error message saying "`Connecting to SFTP server "some.host.com" as "root" ........................................................................ failure (Invalid login/password specified)`"

I'm out of tricks now. I can confirm that the port number is correct, I can use that port number to login using a pk on my Mac.

Here is the setting of my Sublime currently. Can somebody point out what else I could try, please?

```
{
    // The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
    // Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

    // sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "sftp",

    "save_before_upload": true,
    "upload_on_save": true,
    "sync_down_on_open": true,
    "sync_skip_deletes": false,
    "sync_same_age": true,
    "confirm_downloads": false,
    "confirm_sync": true,
    "confirm_overwrite_newer": true,

    "host": "some.host.com",
    "user": "root",
    // "password": "",
    "port": "222",

    "remote_path": "/",
    "ignore_regexes": [
        "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
        "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
        "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
    ],
    //"file_permissions": "664",
    //"dir_permissions": "775",

    //"extra_list_connections": 0,

    "connect_timeout": 30,
    "keepalive": 120,
    //"ftp_passive_mode": true,
    //"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
    "ssh_key_file": "D:/Software/Sublime 3/myKey.ppk",
    //"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

    //"preserve_modification_times": false,
    //"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
    //"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
    //"remote_locale": "C",
    //"allow_config_upload": false,
}
```

P.s. I was told this would be a better place to ask this question. Im new to Superuser so please let me know if there are better ways to get support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you had already got an answer but hopefully this will help someone.

You cant use .pem .ppk is the answer

1. using puttykey gen you need to convert .pem to .ppk
   just load .pem and save as .ppk
2. Use the ppk to connect

here is my example

> ```
> "host": "your server ip",
> "user": "ubuntu", //default
> "ssh_key_file": "c:/your_location/newkey.ppk",
> "remote_path": "/var/www/html/your_webfolder_path/",
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a while. `SFTP` uses `PSFTP` on Windows, so if you load your private ssh key to `Pageant`, it should connect. I specified the `ssh_key_file` path *AND* uploaded to `Pageant`. You might need to convert your `.pem` to `.ppk` first as @Wayne indicated.

*** Not sure if I had to both specify the ssh key path and upload to `Pageant` but once I uploaded to `Pageant` I was able to connect